# Player Controller script not working at all (player is not moving)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a simple cube Player object in unity, with a character controller component with a script, which is literally took from another tutorial, but for some reasons my character is just not moving. I don't know if I made a mistake in the script, or elsewhere, so I'm kinda lost.

Here's my script (PlayerController.cs)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3;
    public float rotationSpeed = 90;
    public float gravity = -20f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 15;

    CharacterController characterController;
    Vector3 moveVelocity;
    Vector3 turnVelocity;

    void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveVelocity = transform.forward * speed * vInput;
            turnVelocity = transform.up * rotationSpeed * hInput;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                moveVelocity.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
            //Adding gravity
            moveVelocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            characterController.Move(moveVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.Rotate(turnVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are applying gravity only when the character is grounded. You should apply gravity all the time to make the character move.

Here is the updated script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3;
    public float rotationSpeed = 90;
    public float gravity = -20f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 15;

    CharacterController characterController;
    Vector3 moveVelocity;
    Vector3 turnVelocity;

    void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveVelocity = transform.forward * speed * vInput;
            turnVelocity = transform.up * rotationSpeed * hInput;

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                moveVelocity.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }

        moveVelocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        characterController.Move(moveVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Rotate(turnVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```